# How to see the frontend in ethercamp's cloud9?

Tags: ide, gui, ether-camp, ethereum-studio

I'm trying to run the example DApp on live.ethercamp.org but following the procedures the stated in ReadMe.md I cant get the webpage up with `http-server`

The browser says:

> **This site can’t be reached**
>
> http://172.17.0.21:8080/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://xxx.by.ether.camp is unreachable.
>   ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Comment: Try replacing the IP with the URL of your c9 / ethereum studio instance.

Comment: Are you using cloud9 in your daily development? @5chdn 
I really want to find out the best practice here, what tools people like and what not. Unfortunately such a Question would solicit too opinion based Answers for StEx. but a comment would be really appreciated

Comment: @RolandKofler you can always find me in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34620/whisper) by the way. Cloud9 is good, [Ethereum Studio](http://blog.ether.camp/post/142794388568/ethereum-studio-is-ready-for-you) is better.

Comment: Perfect, I'm gonna ping you tomorrow about some opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the IP with the URL of your cloud9 or Ethereum Studio instance.

http://xxx.by.ether.camp:8080/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://xxx.by.ether.camp

Where `xxx` is your username on ether.camp.